# Pyspark: Dropping columns with no distinct values only using transformations

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a huge dataframe with 1340 columns. Before diving into modelisation, I must get rid of columns with no distinct values. The few ways I found to do it require **Actions** on the dataframe i.e. it takes much time (approx: 75 hours). How to solve this only using **Transformations** in order to save a lot of time ?

I'm using Azure Databricks that runs Apache Spark 2.4.0 and Python 3.5.
Cluster specs:
- Worker: 56 GB memory, 16 cores
- Driver: 56 GB memory, 16 cores
2-8 nodes (autoscalling)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
# This shouldn't be run

cols_to_drop = []

for c in df.columns:
  # Extracting the value computed by countDistinct()
  # Here collect() is time-consuming because it's an action
  if df.agg(countDistinct(c)).collect()[0][0] < 2:
    print("{} has no distinct values.".format(c))
    cols_to_drop.append(c)

print(len(cols_to_drop))
df = df.drop(*cols_to_drop)
```

Also I tried using approx_count_distinct which is supposed to be faster with an estimation error > 0.01. But it didn't change much and was often longer.

I'd like something that does the same job - dropping columns with no distinct values - with no function that implies action such as collect().

**Edit**:
It's not recommended for large datasets, but I did it anyway. Converting my dataframe into a pandas dataframe with toPandas(). Took 10 minutes, which is pretty decent. Then this does the trick:

```
cols_to_drop = [c for c in f.columns if len(df[c].unique()) < 2]
```

Comment: 1) You're calling `collect` in a loop for each column- of course that's going to be slow. 2) If you can convert to pandas, then you should probably just use pandas. My rule of thumb is use spark only when you can't do it in memory or it's too slow.

Comment: pault 1) Do you have any other solution ? Which is the point of my question
2) I mainly use spark and it's going great so far. Pandas calls will be processed by the driver only and it's going to be way longer. Fortunately, in most cases you have efficient pyspark functions.

Comment: The topic you posted is indeed really close to my question and someone posted a solution that is really likely to work (pyspark + pandas).

Comment: Any solution on speeding the above  process on larger dataset using pyspark ? Its taking too much time to drop the clomuns when i use pyspark.